# List View Read and Unread messages

Tags: android, listview, hashmap, simpleadapter, read-unread

I have a `list view` in which i show the list of messages. I am using `SimpleAdapter` to show the listview. I have a flag(true/false) set in the `hash map`(that shows whether message is read or not).Its working properly. I could update flag once it is read. How to differentiate read and unread messages(I just want bold text view for unread message).

Comment: compare the values from the hash map and set for those which are false TextView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);

Comment: what is your question basically? do you want answer for how to differentiate or you want to know how to make a specific textview with bold text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a DerivedBaseAdapter. In the getView() method check the true/false for the key value. Correspondingly make the text in the listView bold.

Comment: yea i have created a custom adapter. and that solved. thanks.